# navigate to another HTML using windows 8 apps

Tags: rest, windows-8, navigation, xmlhttprequest

My code is:

```
var userName = document.getElementById("txtSearch").value;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "http://www.rest.net/services/abc.svc/json/GetXml", true);
    xhr.responseType = "text";
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
    var packet = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><CompanyRequest xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/abc.DomainModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><CompanyName>company</CompanyName></CompanyRequest>';
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState==xhr.DONE) {            
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var response = parser.parseFromString( xhr.responseText, "text/xml");
            var n = response.getElementsByTagName("CompanyResponse");               
            for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
                var p = n[i].getElementsByTagName("CompanyList1");
                for (var j = 0; j < p.length; j++) {
                    var l = p[j].getElementsByTagName("Company");
                    for (var k = 0; k < l.length; k++) {
                        var a = l[k].getElementsByTagName("Id")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

                        if (a != null) {
                            sessionStorage.setItem(1, a);
                            WinJS.Navigation.navigate("Search.html");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    xhr.send(packet);
```

I am very new to this. I want to navigate to search.html page on button click. But it is not going so...what's wrong with it i cant understand...help me..

Thanks in advance..........

Comment: Did you try the relative path for Search.html? Eg: /pages/Search.html or something like that?

Comment: it is not placed in any folder.. so gave it like that...is there any error?

Comment: No, I just thought that perhaps your server was not able to locate the file due to the path. But if it's in the same path, then it should be fine. What is the error that you are getting in the browser?

Comment: no error.. just it cant able to redirect. is this single line enough to redirect  WinJS.Navigation.navigate("Search.html"); or any more needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Navigation Template from visual studio, then you need to:

- Make sure your Page is registered with that name
- Make sure that Page control is being instantiated

The WinJS.Navigation namespace is **not** intended for navigating the application to internet-urls; it's intended to manage navigation *within* the application e.g. files already in your package.

If your trying to navigate the whole application, you can set window.location.href to the full URL you wish to navigate to. This will tear down your current script state and move you wholesale to that page.

If you really are using single page navigation, I suggest stepping into the navigate call you have, and seeing where it leads you to verify you've correctly registered the destination & the Navigation Template sample code is doing it's work.